# When Using the "Efficient Adapter", holder is sometimes null

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm using a mixture of the "[Efficient Adapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)" and the [EndlessAdapter](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) from CommonsGuy, and sometime the holder in getView() is null.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.queue_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queueItemText);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queueItemImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (holder != null) {
        holder.text.setText(queueItems.get(position).getTitle().getName());
    } else {
        Log.e(context.getString(R.string.app_name), "holder is null for some reason ...");
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

I've put the rest of the code for both of my classes [here](http://pastie.org/private/0nrue2mzuvnqp2tm8ld6nw), as it's rather large to paste inline.

Once the whole data set is loaded, scrolling up & down causes rows to disappear and re-appear too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest `EndlessAdapter`, as it was updated a few weeks ago as I recall.

If that does not help, and if you can give me a full project (not just a couple of classes) that replicates the problem, I can try to fix it. Please contact me via the [`cw-android` Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android), which is the primary home for support for `EndlessAdapter` and my other components.

Comment: I'm using 0.2.1 from github.

I'll have to create something that replicates the issue (unless you have a Lovefilm dev account that you can use the keys from :-)

Give me a few days and I'll be in touch via the Google group.

Comment: @Stuart Grimshaw: Since I've never heard of "Lovefilm", I'm guessing that I don't have a dev account... :-) I look forward to the sample project, so I can squash the bug.

Comment: There are accounts you can use, but it requires me to enter my credit card details, which obviously I don't want to do :-)

I'm trying to recreate the problem without using an external datasource.